# Bucketing the values of a specific variale in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a very basic thing but looks like i am doing something wrong. My goal is to categorize the values of Salary variable in my data frame as low, medium and high. But the manner i am doing i am not getting the intended results. Could yo please point out where am I doing wrong?

```
Salary<-c(30,40,50,60,80,100,200,300)
Sample<-data.frame(Salary)
Sample$Salary[Sample$Salary>=30 & Sample$Salary<=60]<-"low"
Sample$Salary[Sample$Salary>60& Sample$Salary<=100]<-"med"
Sample$Salary[Sample$Salary>100]<-"high"
```

I want values of Salary from 30 till 60 to be categorized as low, values above 60 till 100 as med and values greater than 100 as high. But my above codes produces this result:

> Sample$Salary

[1] "high" "high" "high" "high" "high" "100"  "high" "high"

So where am i at fault? Apologies in advance, this might be a very simple thing and i must be doing something wrong here.

Comment: Use `cut` instead. It is designed for this type of operation. This will work: `cut(Salary, c(30, 60, 100, Inf), labels=c("low", "med", "high"), include.lowest = TRUE)`

Comment: The first replacement causes an implicit conversion of the whole column to `character`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please find the answer for your question.Always try to write this in functions.

```
salary = as.data.frame(c(30,40,50,60,80,100,200,300))


salary_condition = function(x){

if (x >30 & x <= 60){
print("low")
}else if(x>60 & x<=100){
 print("medium")
} else if(x>100){
print("High")
} else {
print("nothing")
```

}
   }

salary_condition(100) will give "medium"